# How to change date format in solr from yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ into “dd/MM/yyyy”?

Tags: solr

I am using solr 4.2 and I have a date field in the database which converted erroneously in solr's date field e.g. the value 2021-05-10 which is stored in the table, is converted into the value 2021-05-09T22:00:00Z in solr. So, what have to do in order to be able to handle the date values as they are, without the time/timezone part?

Comment: Any datestamps in Solr need to be in UTC - so that's the only format you're going to get to use in Solr as long as you want date functions to behave correctly (you can supply the `TZ` parameter in most cases to adjust for your local timezone). The difference seems too large in your example however; 2021-05-09 shouldn't move 22 hours forward in time, but two hours back (if running in CEST) would be reasonable (so 2021-05-08 instead in your example).

Comment: yes, you have right. I did a mistake. the value in the database is 2021-05-10, and it is converted in solr to 2021-05-09T22:00:00Z. There is no way to use the DateFormatTransformer to change the format of the solr date? i have read that "the DateFormatTransformer converts dates from one format to another". I have tried it, but it doesn't do what it supposed to do.

Comment: The `DateFormatTransformer` is to convert random formats into something that Solr can understand when indexing. In your case Solr understands the value and apparently has a good idea about the current timezone. Exactly what is the problem you're encountering? Different problems will have different solutions; when it comes to outputting the format in your frontend, expect every date to be in UTC and convert it to the local timezone on output.